# Difficulty Shrinking Large database files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

My company's primary client database (SQL SERVER 2014) is over 8 TB in size.  As part of our latest project we have moved roughly one third of the data tables to separate AG databases.  We are now looking to delete the tables from the client database and shrink the Database files.  A test of the standard database shrink database and shrink file executions are taking multiple days to complete which is unlikely to finish without being blocked on our production server.

Shrinking the database would be advantageous to cut down on backup size/storage and to reduce the size of the drives the client db is running on so were not paying as much for those either.

Is there a way to tackle this issue other than attempting to shrink the entire database all at once?

Comment: Unless there is a reason to free up disk space, shrinking files is usually a bad idea because it introduces fragmentation. If you need to shrink then I've found that doing it in very small chunks on large DB's works better than at once. But the time will depend on schema and data. I'm about 99% sure that backups only backup the data and not the white space so that extra space won't be backed up.

Comment: @Alen is correct about the backups. They only include the non-empty pages, so anything shrink would be releasing back to disk is already not included in your backups anyway.